# Getting "CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource" when trying to commit using Eclipse subversive plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subversive

I'm using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.7.5, SVN 1.7 and the Eclipse Subversive plugin.  Occassioanlly, when I try and commit changes from my project (by right clicking on the project from the package explorer, selecting "Team" -> "Commit"), I get the error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200007: CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time].
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT request failed on '/svn/subco-digital.coderepo/!svn/rvr/2110/trunk/myproject/src/main/java/org/mainco/subco/myproject/validator/UserFormValidator.java'
```

I have verified that I have checked out the latest version of my project.  How can I take care of these repeated errors?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Cleaning up worked for me:

right click on the <kbd>project</kbd> -> <kbd>team</kbd> -> <kbd>cleanup / refresh</kbd>

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be related to checking out an SVN repository with one version of the SVN client then trying to manage it in Eclipse using a newer version.

Comment: Sometimes I had to force the cleanup using SVN Tortoise, since Eclipse cleanup didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @David. I did the checkout with Tortoise, but tried to commit in Eclipse.

Comment: cleanup from Eclipse is not working for me. Cleanup from SVN Tortoise worked great!

Comment: I had to do 'svn cleanup' from the command line. After that in Eclipse I do refresh, then team->refresh/cleanup

Comment: btw, in my case I think it's related to the fact that I used chmod to remove the executible bit of some files and changed the content as well. I later figured out that I have to use 'svn propdel' to do that.

Answer (score 32):

As I commented in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340137/4226717)...

For those that <kbd>project</kbd> -> <kbd>team</kbd> -> <kbd>cleanup</kbd> doesn't work in eclipse try:

- Force the cleanup using SVN Tortoise
- From terminal with command `svn cleanup /folder_to_cleanup`

Comment: Anyway, @khituras I recommend you to change from svn to git :P

Comment: Oh, I already did, but there are still old projects in svn :-D

Comment: `svn cleanup` worked for me in a way that none of the other suggested interventions on this page did. Thanks!

Comment: On MacOS I used "brew reinstall svn" followed by "svn cleanup /folder_to_cleanup".  Worked great.

Answer (score 31):

This is most likely your console svn version is different to your Eclipse "SVNKIT (Pure Java)" version, you can change Preferences=>Team=>SVN=>SVN interface=>Client using "JavaHL (JNI)"

My case is as below, using Java HL 1.7.10 is ok, but using SVNKIt v1.7.9 will have the problem

```
wuliang-Mac:src wwu$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)
compiled Jul  9 2013, 12:55:03
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.  I'm having trouble getting Eclipse to recognize the JavaHL SVN connector - am currently using the SVNKit connector.  Going to troubleshoot that issue and if that turns out to be the problem, I'll come back and accept.

Comment: Had the same problem with Netbeans. Changing the Client from SvnKit to CLI solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is [bug reported](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-384) in SVNKit with the same error.

Comment: Here is a google cache of the issue for anyone scared to click: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5E_dKYzo78oJ:https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-384&hl=en&gl=us&strip=0&vwsrc=0

Answer (score 3):

In my case, <kbd>project</kbd> -> <kbd>team</kbd> -> <kbd>cleanup / refresh</kbd> worked for one of the files but not the other.  Simply copy the command that failed from svn console on eclipse and run it in console with "svn" prefix works for me.  So the syntax is:

```
svn commit -m "comment" -N /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute from the terminal:

```
svn cleanup
```

Team -> Refresh/Cleaunp from IDE didn't work for me.

Comment: This is the common case for  2020-06 (4.16.0). You have to use the terminal to do the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

I had hard time solving this issue and I finally figured out what happened.

If you use SVN add-on with Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA and **delete some files our of it (from system's file browser**, then you will get this message as well.

The only way I was able to solve it in IDEA was to commit changes via external SVN tool, then reopened the IDE and checkout changes. After that I was able to commit with no such error.

Comment: Nothing new, check @wuLiang´s answer. You have used different versions of SVN clients.

Answer (score 1):

@wu liang asnwer worked for me. but i had to goto
`Preferences=>Team=>SVN=>SVN Connectors=>Native JavaHL`

**screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

Comment: In my SVN Connector only one option is available for select.That is SVNKit 1.8.12..Do  I  have to download the additional connector.

Comment: yes, you can download them [here](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive/download?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive)

Comment: It worked for me and I managed to checkin from eclipse instead of falling back on tortoise client

Answer (score 0):

For whomever is using SmartSVN (in MacOS) and Eclipse, if after clean up at Eclipse using the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269432/418439) is still not working, you may try to clean up at SmartSVN, top menu -> `Modify` -> `Clean Up...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your Eclipse IDE or which ever IDE you are running your java project with. Then open terminal and type this:

svn cleanup /path/to/your/project/rootfolder

Reopen Eclipse IDE and try committing again, this should work!!!

Answer (score -1):

Encounter this when server is upgrading svn version.

For **Idea** *Intellij user*, what we need to do is

1. select the project root directory in the left project panel
2. in the top menu, select `VCS -> Subversion -> Cleanup`

Now you should be able to checkin/out.

Comment: This answer would be ok if the question was for *Intellij*. However it is for Eclipse subversive plugin.

Comment: @FLBKernel, i was led to this question when google searching this *SVN* error. So i thought it might save some other `Intellij` user some time in case google also take them here. Anyway~~

Comment: I thought this question was useful despite not being eclipse related. Good for people who are directed here by the same google search.