# Cannot Commit to the SVN - CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time]

Tags: svn, commit, checkin

I am trying to commit some classes and XML files to SVN but I keep getting this error message:

> svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: E200007: CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time].
>   svn: E175002: CHECKOUT request failed on '/svn/SriLankaLottery-app/!svn/rvr/31/trunk/DealsDirect/src/com/elottery/Login.java'

I also tried to update the code and then commit, but it still does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource" when trying to commit using Eclipse subversive plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816012/getting-checkout-can-only-be-performed-on-a-version-resource-when-trying-to-co)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have a clean up and see, normally it works.

right click on the project -> team -> cleanup / refresh

Comment: yeah it worked. Thanks Maheel..I guess some old svn files prevented my files being checked in.

Comment: Not work for me, finally type 'svn cleanup /folderNameYouWantToClean' in terminal and resolve my stuck.

Answer (score 11):

For those that <kbd>project</kbd> -> <kbd>team</kbd> -> <kbd>cleanup</kbd> doesn't work in eclipse try:

- Force the cleanup using SVN Tortoise
- From terminal with command `svn cleanup /folder_to_cleanup`

Comment: I would recommend to change from svn to git though

Comment: you can ommit the folder, when you are in the root folder of your working copy

Answer (score 5):

clean/refresh does not work for me.(Mac OSX+eclipse+SVNKit)I just copy my project from mac to Windows, and commit success with TortoiseSVN. I did't get the work reason, but if someone stuck here(clean/refresh not work) may try this way.

EDIT: this is might Subclipse's bug, finally I type 'svn cleanup /folderNameYouWantToClean' in terminal  and resolve the issue.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer to me. I faced the same issue in Ubuntu v16 and resolved it using the cleanup command in the Terminal

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same error in Netbeans, similar solution Right click project - > Subversion - > clean up working copy

Comment: In NB 8.1 this is now: Right click -> Subversion -> Working Copy -> Cleanup

Comment: Sometimes with Netbeans doesn't work. But you can run the command in your terminal `svn cleanup` within your project directory in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

in my case JavaHL was not present (Eclipse -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN, client)

to install it

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/* /usr/lib/
```

Now restart Eclipse and you should be able use Subsclipse with JavaHL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, 
Working on windows and netbeans, and I don't have console access.
- I tried cleaning up project, did'nt work
- project > subversion > working copy > clean up, did'nt work
Then 
**browse into winodws files

find the project 

right click

chose TortoiseSVN

Cleanup...

checked: clean up working copy status and include externals (they are set as default)**
That's all, I was able to commit from netbeans enviroment.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I fixed it by checking out the project using NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this problem using Eclipse Mars and SVNKit 1.8.14.

Cleanup didn't solve the problem.

I changed the SVN Connector to Native JHL 1.9.3, and it worked right away.